# How to establish a one-to-many relationship to a model whose type is stored in db

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, model

I have a database that looks like this: [Database Graphical Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZblgK.png)

The `dance_performer.perfomer_type` field hosts values such at `'\App\Dancer'`, `'\App\Couple'` or `'\App\Formation'`.

How would you proceed to connect the `dance_performer.perfomer_id` to the different models? I am not sure how I am supposed to write the relationships in the different models.
Should I create a `\App\Performer` model which would then direct to one of the three previously mentioned?

I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Look for `morph` in Laravel documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I have the required reputation to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `polymorphic` relationships. See documentations https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships